# Does $\frac{1}{x}$ have a linear approximation at $x=0$?

Tags: calculus

I know that $\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{a^2}(x-a)$ is the formula for the linear approximation to $\frac{1}{x}$ at point $x=a$. But, when I set $a=0$, I found myself in a division by zero, that is not possible.

I thought that every single function could be approximated by a polynomial from every point! If so, for this particular function there will not be a Maclaurin polynomial!

Thanks.

Comment: No, there isn't. Go back and look at the hypotheses required for such a thing to exist.

Comment: You may be curious about [Laurent series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every function that is **defined** and **differentiable** at $a$ has a linear approximation at $a$.  The function $\frac{1}{x}$ is not defined at $0$ so it has no linear approximation at $0$.

Remember that the linear approximation is just the tangent line at $a$.  Take a look at the graph of $\frac{1}{x}$ and ask yourself if there is a tangent line at $0$.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. Thanks